# Django Forms.py Change EmailField Value To Auto Populated value="{{ user.email }}"

Tags: python, django, forms

I want my Django form's EmailField to auto populate with the user's email. How does this get accomplished? I am not using models.py with this form.

Full Code:
https://dpaste.org/4PrR

Instead of 'value':'hi' I want 'value':{{ user.email }}

Code from forms.py:

```
payment_email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off', 'type':'email', 'id':'email', 'value':'hi', 'readonly':'readonly'}), required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['payment_email'].label = "Email:"
```

Comment: pass `user.email` instead of hi.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I am getting NameError: name 'user' is not defined. What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) parameter when instantiating your form.

```
form = PaymentForm(data, initial={'payment_email': user.email})
```

Comment: Where would I put this code in the views.py or the forms.py? I am also getting an error with @MD.KhairulBasar's suggestion above.

Comment: after trying a few things I got it to work. In the view, I needed form = PaymentForm(initial={'payment_email': request.user.email}) and form = PaymentForm(data, initial={'payment_email': request.user.email}). Thank you very much!